# ZeosLib with MYSQL's shared memory protocol?

Tags: mysql, delphi, shared-memory, lazarus, zeos

I started up my local MYSQL server with the shared memory protocol turned on.
How can I connect to my server with [ZeosLib](http://zeos.firmos.at/)? Where do I specify that it is using shared-memory?

I am using Lazarus(freepascal), although the directions would be the same for Delphi (probably).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the [`TZConnection`](http://test.bravecobra.com/zeoslib/components/html/d4/d01/class_t_z_connection.html) has no connection string property you can set the additional connection parameters in [`TZConnection.Properties`](http://test.bravecobra.com/zeoslib/components/html/da/d8b/class_t_z_abstract_connection.html#a9fa1a4b5fc4df84c01f7bb879a3f1bde).

I presume you run your MySQL server this way

```
mysqld --skip-networking --shared_memory=1 --shared-memory-base-name='MyMemoryDB'
```

To enable your shared memory connection you might try to add the following configuration lines into the property [`TZConnection.Properties`](http://test.bravecobra.com/zeoslib/components/html/da/d8b/class_t_z_abstract_connection.html#a9fa1a4b5fc4df84c01f7bb879a3f1bde) at design time in Object Inspector.
Note that the [`protocol`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol) must be set as it is and [`shared-memory-base-name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html#option_general_shared-memory-base-name) to the same value as you used in the command line parameter. The default value is MYSQL so if you omit the parameter in command line then you should change the following MyMemoryDB values to MYSQL.

So in [`TZConnection.Properties`](http://test.bravecobra.com/zeoslib/components/html/da/d8b/class_t_z_abstract_connection.html#a9fa1a4b5fc4df84c01f7bb879a3f1bde) property try to add these two lines

```
protocol=memory
shared-memory-base-name=MyMemoryDB
```

or at runtime in the [`TZConnection.BeforeConnect`](http://test.bravecobra.com/zeoslib/components/html/da/d8b/class_t_z_abstract_connection.html#a5b43212e8b8e294b83ccbe76cc909a13) event handler use

```
procedure TForm1.ZConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZConnection1.Properties.Add('protocol=memory');
  ZConnection1.Properties.Add('shared-memory-base-name=MyMemoryDB');
end;
```

Hope this will help you somehow. I haven't tested it because I don't have the proper environment.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** ZeOS support it, it is probably a textual property that can be added to the (TZ)connection options. Just like other clientlib properties.